# Android app bundle for dynamic feature delivery including contentProvider can fail

Tags: android-contentprovider, android-app-bundle

Trying to publish a new app (it's a launcher, it is kind of important too) with the new App Bundle format can be tricky if we have the following parameters:

- use the app bundle aab publishing format
- use the dynamic feature delivery (on demand delivery)
- the feature module includes a `ContentProvider` in a sub-library

This approach has caused several issues:

1. because of class not found issues, the `ContentProvider` in the module cannot be enabled, it should disabled in the main manifest, and then be enabled afterward programmatically when the dynamic feature has been downloaded and is available for the main app.
2. if we use the `SplitCompatInstall`, the feature can well download, but actually it is emulated as first and not installed which causes the next issue
3. if the app needs to restart, since the contentProvider has been programmatically enabled, and since it is persisted, it tries to restart. Which fails because the dynamic feature is not yet installed- actually re-installed with `SplitCompat.install()` - so the class loader cannot find the according class and the app crashes.
4. if the app is a launcher, which automatically is restarted by system, there is a crash loop!

So for this particular case, I recommend not to use `SplitCompat.install`
Prefer using `deferredInstall()` which download the feature apks, then post a task for a proper install by the android play.core.

The drawback of this strategy is you cannot control when the app feature  is installed. You may have to wait for your app be in background so that it installs with the new feature.

If your app is a launcher which always has a running thread , it may never happens, even at rebooting (what I see).
Finally when you udpate your app through Playstore it finally installs with all dynamic feature apks (and related component, like the `ContentProvider`)

I am open to discuss this topic

Code to enable or disable a `ContentProvider`:

```java
    public static void enableMyProviderForDynamicFeature(final Context context, final boolean enable) {
        Log.d("DebugDynamicFeature", "com.duapps.ad.stats.MyProvider"+ (enable?" enabling":" disabling"));
        final ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, "com.duapps.ad.stats.MyProvider");
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, enable ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem here, I have declared ContentProvider in my dynamic module's manifest, and it works fine if we use bunble tool to build the aab and zip it to a single apk. But the problem occurred if we didn't include the dynamic module's apk into our build. It seems that our base.apk will always include manifest from dynamic modules even if it it is declared as on-demand, this would result in ClassNotFoundException for us. This issue also blocks our automation test since androidTest task would install the bask.apk excluding dynamic modules.